# Javascript/Jquery Slide effect happening in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a section of my page that incorporates the Jquery slide effect but the `div` that is supposed to slide into the place of the original is sliding too low, then just popping into place. I'm not quite sure why it is behaving this way. What should I do to make the new `div` slide on the same plane as the original `div`? Below is my JS as well as a link to a fiddle so you can see what I mean exactly. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/vYDqC/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#content div").hide();
$("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current");
$("#content div:first").effect("slide", 800);
var animating = false;
$('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){
    return;       
    }
    else{
        if(!animating)             
            $("#content div").hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 800, function() { animating = true; });
            $("#tabs li").attr("id","");
            $(this).parent().attr("id","current");
            $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 800, function() { animating = false;});
    }
});
});
```

Comment: the problem probably lies in your css

Comment: I was thinking that might be an issue, the CSS is in the fiddle, but I'm going to add it here as well

Comment: EDIT: Not adding the CSS, it's too bulky and I don't want to take up space... It's included in the link above though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem before with jQuery's slide effect. Try adding `position: absolute` to your `.con` class. Then you'll want to add `width: 100%` for it to fill out the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/vYDqC/2/